# MYSQL: varchar vs int for storing a variable

Tags: mysql

For readability reasons I would like to store a variable as a varchar such as "in", "out", "auto" instead of as a int such as "0", "1", "2". Are there any reasons why I shouldn't store it as a varchar?

The reason I ask is that I have heard that int is faster but does that apply in this scenario or will the speed difference be so small that it is negligible?

I am quite new to MYSQL so please let me know if you need any more information, I have searched for similar questions/answers but haven't found any that answer my question.

Comment: you could use enum too. Many will argue that smallint 1 is ideal for this but unless you are planning to migrate to some other db you should be fine with enum or varchar. Not likely you will notice a lag

Comment: I think u have answered it yourself, as to when does it make a difference. That depends on how big is ur database

Comment: Just to chime in, the speed difference probably won't even register. It's less than negligible, because it's probably less than the quantum length of the CPU, so it's not going to take cycles away from other processes, including itself.

Comment: At what point do you think that it would make a difference? E.g. if I had to sort 100 columns that contained "in" instead of searching for "0" would it make much difference? Or would it have to be 1000, 10000, etc to be noticeable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a simple rule of thumb: If you need to do arithmetic or indexing, use a numeric type, if not use a character type.

As rules of thumb typically depend on the size and angle of the thumb in question, here is what I mean:

- (Classic example #1) Phone number: No arithmetic makes sense, use a VARCHAR and get a free collection of `+` and `()` extras
- (Classic example #2) ZIP code: Again no arithmetic, our british friends living in something like `LO7SWF` will be gratefull, if you use a VARCHAR
- One of a set, e.g. 0-9: If these are the PKs of a lookup table (as they should be), use an int. If their meaning is outside of the DB consider using a VARCHAR (and smile, if the hardware vendor upgrades from strictly-numerical keypads to ones also  using `#` and `*`)

While it is strictly true, that an index over a VARCHAR field with numerical-only content of 11 figures is slightly slower than an INT(11), I have yet to see the real-world DB, where this makes an appreciable difference.